# Oracle Forms and Reports : REP-51002

Tags: forms, oracle, report

I try to call a report from a form in Oracle Forms and Reports, but I get the following error :

"REP-51002: Echec de liaison avec le serveur Reports Server repsrvr"

Anyone has an idea what could be the reason of this ? I need your help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try googling "REP-51002" first? https://community.oracle.com/thread/200082?start=0&tstart=0 is among the first results, mentioning many possible reasons.

Comment: It was the first thing I did of course, but in vain.

Comment: It seems you have not installed report server properly. Have you changed port during installation, which oracle version?

Comment: I got everything already installed in a Windows XP virtual machine, I didn't do the installation myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution (finally !) .. for those who may encounter the same problem :

1) Search the file rwnetwork.conf

2) Change the lines :

```
<multicast channel="228.5.6.7" port="14021" timeout="1000" retry="5"/>
<!--namingService name="Cos" host="127.0.0.1" port="14021"/-->
```

Into

```
<!--multicast channel="228.5.6.7" port="14021" timeout="1000" retry="5"/-->
<namingService name="Cos" host="127.0.0.1" port="14021"/>
```

3) Start the namingservice : namingservice 14021

Credits to Denis Segard-Oracle from community.oracle.com