# REP-51002: Bind to Reports Server rep_server failed

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, report, oraclereports

I want to run reports 10g from forms 10g. But we got error REP-51002: Bind to Reports Server rep_server failed

Kindly help me how to resolve this error

Comment: Do you know your reports server name, and what do you get when you call `https://yourDomaiNorIPforRepserver/reports/rwservlet/showjobs?server=rep_server_name` from a web browser ?

Comment: Before you ask look for answers here and on the internet in general. There is a big possibility this question has already been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547679/oracle-forms-and-reports-rep-51002